# Hot reloading with typescript and node

Tags: node.js, typescript, hot-reload

A lot of articles exist out there explaining how to hook up `nodemon` or `ts-node-dev` to automatically restart your TypeScript server on file changes, but restarting the whole server is starting to get pretty slow on my large TypeScript project, where startup times can take many tens of seconds (thanks `typeorm`).

Frontend development has been dominated by boilerplates like `create-react-app`, `nextjs` and more that offer hot reloading without even a page refresh, resulting in very fast feedback times for frontend changes.

What's the equivalent for doing that on a Node API, especially one where the source files are in TypeScript, not JS? Should I be using `tsc --watch` and then invalidating `require.cache` as compiled output completes or something?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/hediet/node-reload) library out.

Comment: Did you try tsc-w with nodemon using concurrently?

Comment: @MBB i'm specifically asking how not to reload the entire node server on file changes, see my question.

Comment: @Eldar ill give it a go, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We use

````
/* eslint-env node */

import path from 'path';

import {
  disposeOnReload,
  enableHotReload,
  getReloadCount,
  hotClass,
  hotRequire,
  hotRequireExportedFn,
  registerUpdateReconciler
} from '@hediet/node-reload';
import { IStart, Logger } from './interfaces';
import { initNextJs } from './modules/application/initNextJs';
import { Globals } from './global';

const index = path.join(__dirname, '../client/index.html');

enableHotReload({ entryModule: module, loggingEnabled: false });
registerUpdateReconciler(module);

Logger.log('[ADMIN] Globals.init()');
Globals.init();

@hotClass(module)
class Loader {
  private v1 = 1; // for reload

  static start(info: IStart) {
    return new Promise<void>((done) =>
      hotRequire<typeof import('./server')>(module, './server', (server) => {
        Logger.log('[ADMIN] server.start()');
        server
          .start(info)
          .then(() => {
            done();
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            Logger.error('[ADMIN] Error starting!', { error });
            process.exit(1);
          });
        return {
          dispose: () => {
            Logger.log('[ADMIN] server.stop()');
            server.stop();
          }
        };
      })
    );
  }
}

let startInfo: IStart;
hotRequireExportedFn(module, Loader, { hasFnChanged: 'useSource' }, (loader) => {
  const reloadCount = getReloadCount(module);
  if (reloadCount === 0) {
    Logger.log('[ADMIN] initNextJs');
    const nextApp = initNextJs(true);
    console.time('************************************************** Prepared Next');
    const preparing = nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
      console.timeEnd('************************************************** Prepared Next');
    });
    startInfo = { nextApp, index, preparing };
  }
  setTimeout(() => loader.start(startInfo), 0);
  return { dispose: () => console.log('loader.dispose()') };
});```
````